# Getting list of primary keys through reverse ForeignKey using values/values_list

Tags: django, django-models

I'm optimising some queries to return only the information we need using `values_list` rather than loading entire objects from the database.

For each object, I need to access the set of its children for some information.

My code is structured similar to this:

```
class MyObj(models.Model):
    field_a = models.Integer()

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(MyObj, related_name='children')
    field_b = models.Integer()
```

For each `MyObj`, I'd like to access the values of `field_b` for all its children as efficiently as possible.

I expected that a query such as `models.MyObj.values_list('children__field_b')` would return a list of the values I wanted, but it only returns a single value.

Is it possible to get a list of values for a field like I've described using `values_list`?

If not, what would be the most performant way of iterating over each `MyObj` and its children?

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = MyObject.objects.get(pk=1)
foo.child_set.values_list('field_b')
```